# how to do deletion of an element from array in python without using builtin functions

Tags: python

How to delete element in an array without using python builtin functions

I have tried this program with builtin functions, but I do not know how to do it without them

```
c = [6,7,8,9]
c.remove(c[0])
print(c)
```

I am getting expected result but I want it without using the built-in function in python.

Comment: Basically every operation on a list (!) will call a method of it.

Comment: you want to say, without using .remove method?

Comment: you mean not to use del keyword? there are no delete methods on lists

Comment: @rusu_ro1 yes brother without using remov & del functions,as we use to do in java.

Comment: you want to remove all the elements that have a certain value, or by index, so you want to delete a certain element?

Comment: @rusu_ro1, I will give any input of element just like I give 3 as a input and it matches with the element in array, so it should be deleted. yeah certain value so called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you know the index of the element that you want to remove:

1) you can concatenate 2 slices of your list that has all  the elements except the one you want to remove:

```
index_to_remove = 0
c = c[0:index_to_remove] + c[index_to_remove + 1:]
```

2)  or by filtering using list comprehension:

```
c = [e for i, e in enumerate(c) if i != index_to_remove]
```

if you just want to delete the first element that has a certain value you can use the same methods, you just set:

```
index_to_remove = c.index(my_value)
```

Comment: thanks for the help, code is working perfectly but i have one more question what does c = [e for i, e in enumerate(c) if i != index_to_remove] this statement do? i have used it but i do not know whats going in it.

Comment: enumerate will give you the index and the value, just make sure you are not keeping the index that you wan to remove (if i!= index_to_remove)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it, but this method creates a new array

```
c=[6,7,8,9]
d=[]
a=0
for x in c:
   if x!=c[a]: #or you write c[0] and remove the a=0
      d.append(x)

print(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use a list comprehension:

```
c = [ e for e in c if e != c[0] ]
```

However, if you have multiple instances of the c[0] value, they will all be removed.

removing by index can also be done using a list comprehension:

```
c = [ e for i,e in enumerate(c) if i != 0 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from array import *   
arr = array("i",[2,4,6,8,9])        
del arr[2]         
print(arr)
```

output-array("i",[2,4,8,9])

Comment: The OP didn't want to use the `del` method - however, I also don't know why.